# How to fix horse spine?

Tags: animation, rigging

sorry I can't think of a better way to phrase this question.

I have been working on a horse walk animation for quite awhile now. I am pretty inexperienced with rigging and animation in general, but I am quite familiar and comfortable with Blender as a whole.

Following various image references & video tutorials I have the horse legs working in the way I want.

Edit: Link to armature & keyframes
[image]

[image: Noodleboy.GIF]

Now to make Horse really shine, I want to animate his spine bouncing with him. Following this reference image [image: Noodlewalk.JPG] I can see the stages where his spine should move to certain places, but my rig doesn't transform the way I need it to.

The biggest issue is when I try to make his butt go down, it makes the whole front half of him shoot straight up into space.

[image: Horsetronaut.PNG]

I've tried to re-rig it quite a few times, but I am getting the feeling that I am missing something to make it work the way I need. Is it possible I need to use an IK Constraint from the Back to front? I haven't seen anyone use a method like that, but I am very confused on how to approach this problem.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (armature only)

Comment: Can do. Didnt have a chance to do so yet for time but I can tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, considering how your armature is made, you should parent *InverseKack* and *Spine02* to *SpineCTRL*. At the end, parent SpineCTRL and all the IK controllers and targets to the root bone. Now when you move up and down *SpineCTRL*, the whole back of your horse follows, as it is supposed to do.

[image]

Comment: Great diagram, thank you much!